# Como fazer um streaming de áudio com ionic?

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs, ionic

Preciso fazer um streaming de áudio com ionic, já instalei diversos plugins mas o streaming não funciona, usando protocolo http e rtsp. Tentei também colocando uma função Javascript dentro do index do app mas nada do streaming funcionar.

Comment: Já tentou: http://www.joshmorony.com/spotify-player-ionic/

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo a utilização da library BinaryJS. Ele é muito bom para ser usado no angular, uma vez que suporta streaming bidirecional.

A utilização dele é extremamente simples, veja se satisfaz sua necessidade: 
http://binaryjs.com/